# Implementing collision detection on a curve in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, pygame

I have wrote a class in python that will randomly generate a line with a curve at the end. I've added movement to the class using an two variable: xChange and yChange. I've tried to add collision detection to the curve by calculating a y value (testY) which I got by rearranging the equation of an ellipse ((x-h)^2/a^2 + (y-k)^2/b^2 = 1).

```
if playerC[0] >= self.x1 and playerC[0] <= self.x4:
            #Tests if the player coords are the same as the curves Y
            testY =  self.k + (self.b*math.sqrt(self.a**2-self.h**2+2*self.h*playerC[0]-playerC[0]**2))/self.a
            pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, WHITE, [0, testY ], [1000, testY])
```

playerC[0] is the fixed x-coordinate I need collision detection on.
I've tried using the same code on another project and it worked fine, however using it in this format seems to break it. 
self.h and self.k are the only variables which will change.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? It is not clear from the description. The code you provide is a good start, but doesn't contain any collision detection, just drawing. Be clear about what you observe from the current code and what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the idea that the curve is some randomly curving line-section.

I would first calculate a bounding box for the curve, using this to initially perform a fast and efficient *does-it-collide-at-all* test.  If the player does not collide with a bounding box, no further tests are needed.

Now it's been determined that `playerC` is in the vicinity of the curve, the code can do further tests.  Depending on the size / complexity / shape of your curve, it may be efficient to split the line into *N* sub-lines (say 8?), and then bounding-box test those sections against your player.  If high accuracy is needed, then further test against the pixels (or further sub-sub-lines) of the curve.

This type of splitting and testing is often implemented with a [quadtree data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).  Using a quadtree mimics the process above.  It quickly finds the relevant part of the collision test, so that means the code is not spending a huge amount of time processing thousands of points.

Failing all this, generate the list of points for the line, and test these (plus th e movement offset) against the player's bounding box.